# Double dependency property adds precision when used with float

Tags: c#, wpf, double, type-conversion, dependency-properties

i wrote my own input-box for numbers. it takes two limits (min and max) and does some validation on the entered number. the two limits are double dependency properties:

```
// minimum acepted value
public double Min
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(MinProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MinProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty MinProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Min", typeof(double), typeof(NumberInputBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

it all works fine, but when i use it with `float` it displayes more than i like. lets say `0.7` is displayed as `0.699999988079071`. how can i prevent that? it works fine with `int` and `double`.

Comment: Not having the code of your `NumberInputBox` I can't get into too much detail. But if the implementation is yours, I'd add a `Format` property where you can specify how many significant digits you want to show in the text representation of the numeric value. For example, "#,##0.0". The issue you are seeing is due to the representation error of `float`. You can have the same issues with `double` too by the way.

Comment: it is quite a lot code, my `NumberInputBox`. but i did just this now: `this.min = Math.Round(min, 3);`. three digits are acurate enough.